# Inserting users using PDO prepared statements

Tags: php, sql, mysql, security, pdo

I made a small script to update fields in a database. I'm using PDO to connect to MySQL. All the business logic of PHP is in the top half of the file, and the form is at the bottom.

Here is the full code. If it's a POST request, it opens the PDO connection and inserts the values from the form.

```
<?php

/**
 * Use an HTML form to update the users table 
 * with new entries.
 *
 */

if ($_POST) 
{

    require_once "config.php";
    require_once "common.php";

    try 
    {
        $connection = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);

        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (firstname, lastname, email, age, location)
                VALUES (:firstname, :lastname, :email, :age, :location)";

        $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);

        $statement->execute(array(
            "firstname" => $_POST['firstname'],
            "lastname"  => $_POST['lastname'],
            "email"     => $_POST['email'],
            "age"       => $_POST['age'],
            "location"  => $_POST['location']
        ));

    }

    catch(PDOException $error) 
    {
        echo $sql . "<br>" . $error->getMessage();
    }
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/primitive.css">
    <title>Update Users</title>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="small-container">
        <h1>Add a user</h1>

            <form method="post">
                <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname">
                <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname">
                <label for="email">Email Address</label>
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
                <label for="age">Age</label>
                <input type="text" name="age" id="age">
                <label for="location">Location</label>
                <input type="text" name="location" id="location">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

I know I can sanitize HTML input by doing something like:

```
function escape($html)
{
    return htmlspecialchars($html, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_SUBSTITUTE, "UTF-8");
}

// example use
escape($_POST['firstname']);
```

I'm wondering how necessary it is when I'm using a prepared statement. I'm still a bit confused about sanitization and filtering, and when it's necessary. I know it's necessary when printing data out to HTML, but not sure how much when receiving input to PDO.

Please forgive any and all ignorance. I'm writing this from scratch and doing my best to teach myself PHP without frameworks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do *not* escape SQL query parameters when using PDO. PDO will do the right thing. If you call unnecessary escaping functions "just in case", then you end up mangling the data. That's how you get junk like "this &amp; that" appearing in some broken web pages.

When *would* you want to escape text using `htmlspecialchars()`? When outputting text to be embedded in HTML. For example,

```
 <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" value="<?php echo escape($_POST['firstname']); ?>">
```

If you didn't call `htmlspecialchars()` on `$_POST['firstname']`, then a malicious user could break the page by inputting a name that contained double-quotes.

Comment: Ah, beautiful. This is what I assumed, but I wanted to be sure before I did it. So if I had my form in one file, and was posting to another via `action="update.php` (for example), I'd use the `escape` method to protect that input data. Makes sense to me! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should be doing field-level validation for all of your input fields before inserting into database (and possibly field-level validation in javascript to even help prevent POST from happening with invalid values).

Sanitization and validation are two different things and both are probably applicable to your typical "input form which inserts into database" use case.

The prepared statement will mitigate against SQL injection attacks and alleviate the need to escape characters for database insertion, but it will not do things such as:

- verify that the email is valid
- verify that age is integer (or integer string)
- verify that name fields are not blank
- etc.

It also does not sanitize against:

- potential XSS attack vectors
- overflow attack vectors
- etc.

You should not even attempt a database insert without knowing you have been passed valid data that has been appropriately sanitized.

Some other thoughts:

- Don't echo out system-level error messages directly to end users. First, they are not user-friendly. Second, they could leak out information you don't want getting out there.
- 'htmlspecialchars()' is not an escaping function.  It is an encoding function used for rendering content into HTML documents.
- You should get in the habit of using session tokens in all your input forms to mitigate against cross-site request forgery (CSRF) attacks.

Comment: Thanks! I do know I should be doing some JavaScript side validation, but I wanted to make sure the security aspect from the PHP end was secure first. 

So, are you saying I should change `$_POST['email']` to `filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL)`, for example?

Thanks for the information, all very useful and informative.

Comment: `filter_var()`, `filter_input()`, `filter_input_array()` would all be good options.

Comment: Downvoted for confusing a beginner by suggesting that protecting against XSS is necessary. That is the kind of FUD that leads beginners to apply all kinds of escapes just in case. There is no XSS problem here, and nothing should be done to guard against it.

Comment: I don't see why `htmlspecialchars()` should not be considered an escaping function.

Comment: Thanks @200_success, I wanted to avoid the issue of putting a bunch of escapes and sanitization in places they don't belong.

Comment: @200_success I simply said that prepared statements don't sanitize against XSS attacks.  I did not suggest that this is applicable to this use case, as we simply don't know how and if the information stored in the database is being rendered back out into pages on the site.  If the answer achieved nothing other than getting OP to perform a Google search on XSS so they are aware of what it is for future use cases, then I am happy to help raise that awareness.

Comment: @MikeBrant if I were to, for example, print out the information in an HTML table on the front end, I would use the escape function I created, correct?

Comment: @TaniaRascia Yes, you would use `htmlspecialchars()` for that.  Your function does nothing other than that, so it probably should not exist.  This would also introduce you to potential XSS vulnerability.

Comment: @MikeBrant the function I made would be useless? I read about it on [this article about preventing XSS attacks](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/06/preventing-xss-vulnerabilities-in-php-everything-you-need-know), so now I'm confused.

Comment: @TaniaRascia It would be useless in the sense of having your own named function.  If all your function does is call `htmlspecialChars()` why do you need it?

Comment: @MikeBrant [Read here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php#111666), found in the PHP docs. I'm just confused as to how it could be an XSS vulnerability. Obviously I don't want to use it if that's the case, but I haven't found anything to support that.

Comment: [Additionally in this](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Security_Cheat_Sheet#XSS_Cheat_Sheet) guide to preventing XSS.

Comment: @TaniaRascia Sorry for confusion in comments.  I meant that displaying information from database to a webpage opens the opportunities for XSS. If you are just collecting data into a database and never rendering it out to web page, there is no XSS vulnerability.

Comment: @MikeBrant No problem. Would I use `htmlspecialchars()` function on the inserting or receiving page? So, `input value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST[]); ?>"` or `<td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row[]); ?></td>` ?

Comment: It would be used in both those cases.  In either case you have a string in a variable that may or may not have bad content in it.